# Как обработать и вернуть код в ajax с той же страницы?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
                            <?php $lists = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM list" ); 
                                $counter=0;
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach($lists as $list){ 
                                $counter++;
                            ?>
                            <td>
                                <a class="pnd-li nonhref" id="<?php echo $list->id ?>" href="?page_id=<?php echo $_GET['page_id'] ?>&pnd=<?php echo $list->id ?>"><p><?php echo $list->number ?></p><p><?php echo $list->addres ?></p></a></td>
                            </td>
                            <?php if($counter == 9){
                                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                                    $counter = 0;
                                } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
```

```js
jQuery(".nonhref").click(function(event){
            var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: href,
                success:function(html){
                    jQuery('.pnd-tables').html(table);
                }
            });
        });
 jQuery(".nonhref").click(function(){
  return false;
 });
```

Есть код, суть в чем. На страницу выводится таблица(кнопки), нужно отправить гет запрос на эту же страницу и в ответе должен быть уже отработанный код который выведется на определенном участве

```
<ul>
                        <?php 
                            function definition($pnd){
                                $ar_pnd=array();
                                foreach($pnd as $pndOtd){
                                    array_push($ar_pnd, $pndOtd->branch);
                                }
                                $ar_pnd=array_unique($ar_pnd);
                                $arr_otd = $ar_pnd;
                                return $arr_otd;
                            }
                            $pndid = 'number_'. $_GET['pnd'];
                            $pnd = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $pndid" );
                            $arr_otd = definition($pnd);
                            foreach($arr_otd as $otd){
                         ?>
                        <li><a href="?page_id=<?php echo $_GET['page_id'] ?>&pnd=<?php echo $_GET['pnd'] ?>&otd=<?php echo $otd ?>" class="nonhref"><?php echo $otd ?></a></li>
                    <?php }?>
                    </ul>
```

Вопрос, как сделать возврат результата этого кода в аякс? Как вообще быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: *в ответе должен быть уже отработанный код который выведется на определенном участве* генерите в php код, отправляете его текстом, на стороне js пишете элементу html(текст)

Comment: а как его отправить текстом?

Comment: например, echo $html;